# Keep getting an error while running Osintgram using git

Tags: python, git, github

I keep getting an error saying-

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\Osintgram\main.py", line 102, in <module>
    pyreadline.Readline().parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 422, in __init__
    BaseReadline.__init__(self)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 62, in __init__
    mode.init_editing_mode(None)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\emacs.py", line 633, in init_editing_mode
    self._bind_key('space',       self.self_insert)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\basemode.py", line 162, in _bind_key
    if not callable(func):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pyreadline\py3k_compat.py", line 8, in callable
    return isinstance(x, collections.Callable)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'`
```

when i was trying to run Osintgram.

I checked for updates in any of the modules but all the requirements were already met.

Comment: _I checked for updates in any of the modules_ How did you do this?  What was the exact command?

Comment: https://github.com/Datalux/Osintgram/issues?q=is%3Aissue+Module+%27collections%27+has+no+attribute+%27Callable%27

Comment: @JohnGordon I just basically used the command to install requirements, which is  `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: @phd thanks so much, the problem is fixed, but now im encountering another error which cant be fixed until next update. (https://github.com/Datalux/Osintgram/issues/756#issuecomment-1584024101)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**https://github.com/Datalux/Osintgram/issues?q=is%3Aissue+Module+%27collections%27+has+no+attribute+%27Callable%27**

this answer is in the github link

credits= @phd

Answer (score 0):

in your **main.py** file, you open it with preferably VS Code or whatever code editor and take "*collections*" out of "*collections*.Callable" and then towards the top you take out "import *collections*" and instead put "import *Callable*" on the top.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).